# Dynamic spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on this new project and I'm trying to set up a dynamic spreadsheet where once one process is complete another will start. To illustrate,

I have a series of payments paying off a mortgage, once the mortgage process is complete (principal remaining is zero) I need the series of payments to start paying off another loan. I'm having a problem setting up the spreadsheet to start one processes when another is done. I think some sort of if function is probably going to come in handy, if anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do goes a little against the grain of Excel, but you can mimic the functionality you want pretty easily.  It would take a second header row.

You don't have a ton of specifics in the prompt, so I'm going to use some general examples.

So, assuming you have your first process information in Column B, and your third process information in Column C, you would place a formula in B2 that determines whether the B process has completed, like:

`=IF(SUM(B3:B400)>=5000,"Done","Not Done")`

Then, your formulas from C3 to C(whatever) would involve:

`=IF($B$2="Done",[Your_Stuff_Here],"")`